# C++ std::forward without T&&

Tags: c++

```
template<typename...Ts>
struct Wrapper{
    using result_type = void (*)(Ts...);

    template<typename T, T (*P)(Ts...)>
    static result_type wrap(){
        return [](Ts...ts) {
            P(forward<Ts>(ts)...); // The forward is required, or the code below will fail.
        };
    };

};

int fun(int&& i, int& j, int k) {
    return 0;
}

auto wrapped = Wrapper<int&&, int&, int>::wrap<int, fun>();
int i = 2;
wrapped(1, i, 3);
```

It works, The problem is, when passed a none reference type, forward will cast it argument to rvalue which means in the above code the third parameter will be moved. So How to forward the exact type without T&&?

Comment: Note that you need to `move` it in regular case: `int bar(std::unique_ptr<int>);`, so `std::forward` is correct.

Comment: Why not just the free function `template <typename T, typename ... Ts> auto wrap(T(*P)(Ts...)) -> void(*)(Ts...) { return [P](Ts...ts) { P(forward<Ts>(ts)...); }; }`

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `static_cast` instead of `forward` here, as your goal is to cast to the exact types specified in `Ts...`:

```
// ...
P(static_cast<Ts>(ts)...);
// ...
```

Comment: Even if it is what OP asked, the `static_cast` might be problematic in some case (as `std::unique_ptr`).